# Why are they called Adverbial?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

> SVA : She was **there**. SVOA : She put the book **on the table**.
>   ([source](http://books.google.co.kr/books?id=TTN1e04S4lgC&pg=PA151&lpg=PA151&dq=quirk%20and%20greenbaum%20svoa&source=bl&ots=-J1MM_ViCE&sig=g_tLSwm1OMlBXy9BqDF-fXg4_ds&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kNN1UbK9LMiuiQeVwICIDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=quirk%20and%20greenbaum%20svoa&f=false))

Is the Adverbial [of [CGEL’s clause types]](http://books.google.co.kr/books?id=TTN1e04S4lgC&pg=PA151&lpg=PA151&dq=quirk%20and%20greenbaum%20svoa&source=bl&ots=-J1MM_ViCE&sig=g_tLSwm1OMlBXy9BqDF-fXg4_ds&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kNN1UbK9LMiuiQeVwICIDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=quirk%20and%20greenbaum%20svoa&f=false) that is necessary in a sentence called because it modifies verb; or because it has the certain semantic meaning, like time, space, etc?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use [adverbial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial) to mean an adverb (e.g. *there*) or a group of words that works as adverb (e.g. "on the table" in "She put the book on the table."), which is normally called [adverbial phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase).